# How to replicate Apache ACE settings & data from one instance to another

Tags: apache, repository, osgi

I want to move Apache ACE repository & settings data (e.g. registered agent, deployment details) to another instance of Apache ACE.

I tried copyping data folders from all the bundle folders from source instance to paste in destination instance and this approach worked as well. But, I find this approach a little error prone.

I was wondering if there is some elegant way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no direct support for this out of the box. Copying the data folders is the only way currently (as you already found out). Although you can use the (internal) APIs of ACE to access this information and write an exporter yourself...